# How to use Zend Framework's Partial Loop with Objects

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I am quite confused how to use `partialLoop`

Currently I use

```
foreach ($childrenTodos as $childTodo) {
  echo $this->partial('todos/_row.phtml', array('todo' => $childTodo));
}
```

`$childrenTodos` is a `Doctrine\ORM\PersistantCollection`, `$childTodo` is a `Application\Models\Todo`

I tried doing

```
echo $this->partialLoop('todos/_row.phtml', $childrenTodos)
          ->setObjectKey('Application\Models\Todo');
```

But in the partial when I try to access properties/functions of my Todo class, I cant seem to get them always ending up with either call to undefined method `Zend_View::myFunction()` when I use `$this->myFunction()` in the partial or if I try `$this->todo->getName()` I get "Call to a member function getName() on a non-object". How do I use partialLoops?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
echo $this->partialLoop('todos/_row.phtml', $childrenTodos)
      ->setObjectKey('object');
```

Then in your partial you can access the object like this

```
$this->object
```

`object` is the name of the variable that an object will be assigned to

You can also do this once in your Bootstrap or other initialization class if you have access to the view object like so

```
protected function initPartialLoopObject()
{
    $this->_view->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('object');

    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->setView($this->_view);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why I am still getting the Call to function on non object error, my code http://pastebin.com/z07phdHj. The strange thing is when I try `echo get_class($this->todo)` i get `Zend_View`

Comment: Can you try setting it in your Bootstrap or similar, it could be that your telling it to use `todo` for objects after the `partialLoop` as run?

Comment: I think it will be a better idea to set it just b4 `echo $this->partialLoop()` as its not a general app thing. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I also had "Call to function on non object" error when trying suggested syntax, seems like they've changed something on later versions of Zend Framework. The following works for me on ZF1.12:

```
echo $this->partialLoop()
->setObjectKey('object')
->partialLoop('todos/_row.phtml', $childrenTodos);
```